# Need to create an edit control that acts like a terminal window

Tags: winforms, mouseevent, edit

I need to create an edit control that takes each line, as entered, and goes off and does an action according to what was entered.  I don't want the user to be able to delete what they typed into the box via their mouse and the delete key. It would look something like this:

> Power On  (user entered this)
>   Power: On Level:50  (what the power on command returned)
>   Laser On (user entered this )
>   Laser: On Power:60 ( what the command returned)

So I don't want them to go back and delete the lines already entered, they can just keep appending items and sending off these commands.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be creating a hybrid UserControl consisting of 2 Textbox's one which is readonly the other being writable. Enter your data in the one, append it to the other when the enter key is pressed, then append the response. Since you haven't stated a programming language here is an example in vb.net.

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            ScrollToEnd(TextBox1)
            TextBox1.Text += TextBox2.Text + vbCrLf
            TextBox1.Text += GetResponse(TextBox2.Text) + vbCrLf
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            ScrollToEnd(TextBox1)
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ScrollToEnd(tb As TextBox)
        tb.SelectionStart = tb.TextLength
        tb.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetResponse(command As String) As String
        Select Case command
            Case "Power On"
                Return "On Level: 50"
            Case "Laser On"
                Return "Laser: On Power:60"
            Case Else
                Return "I do not understand"
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

**UserControl1.Designer.VB's InitializeComponent Method** (*I am only putting this in so you can see the properties of my Controls*)

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.TextBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'TextBox1
    '
    Me.TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.TextBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    Me.TextBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime
    Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
    Me.TextBox1.Multiline = True
    Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
    Me.TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
    Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(253, 181)
    Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.TextBox1.TabStop = False
    '
    'TextBox2
    '
    Me.TextBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.TextBox2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    Me.TextBox2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime
    Me.TextBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 190)
    Me.TextBox2.Name = "TextBox2"
    Me.TextBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(253, 17)
    Me.TextBox2.TabIndex = 1
    '
    'TableLayoutPanel1
    '
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50.0!))
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1, 0, 0)
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox2, 0, 1)
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 89.09953!))
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10.90047!))
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(259, 211)
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'UserControl1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(7.0!, 16.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TableLayoutPanel1)
    Me.Name = "UserControl1"
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(259, 211)
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
```